# Access: Get list of all columns in DB that have "unicode compression"

Tags: sql, ms-access, compression

In Microsoft Access , is it possible somehow to get a list (via a SQL query ) of all columns that have UNICODE compression enabled ?  Maybe by executing a query on some Microsoft Access system table ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no there is no way via a SQL call unless you use something like [OleDbConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309488).

You can determine if Unicode compression is set by seeing if the field object contains a Property called `UnicodeCompression`. So, something along the lines of:

```
Public Sub HasUnicodeCompression( field As DAO.Field )
    Dim oProperty As DAO.Property

    For Each oProperty In field.Properties
        If oProperty.Name = "UnicodeCompression" Then 
            HasUnicodeCompression = True
            Goto CleanUp
        End If
    Next oProperty

    HasUnicodeCompression = False

CleanUp:    
    Set oProperty = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: @MadSeb If you are going to use this to get the fields (columns) with unicode compression, you may as well take the extra step of changing the value here. In general, it is best to use DAO rather than ADO with Access when working with tables, you can do a lot more.